# #1172 - Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, xampp

I am receiving `#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row` error whenever I try to insert some values in my table in MYSQL, I searched for this error and found out that the trigger is giving the problem (it has `SELECT INTO` statement in it)

Following is my trigger code

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER book
AFTER INSERT ON books
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE slot_id INT;
SELECT slotno INTO slot_id FROM books WHERE slotno = new.slotno;
UPDATE slots SET slot_status = 0 WHERE slotno = slot_id;
END;
$
```

this code was working fine when I tried it for the first time but now after some weeks it is giving this error
pls tell me how can I resolve it or how can I implement the same thing without triggers

How is this `SELECT INTO` statement returning more than one row?

Comment: How many books can be put in a slot

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. 
If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided.

Comment: *`SELECT slotno INTO slot_id FROM books WHERE slotno = new.slotno;`* may be replaced with simple `SET slot_id = new.slotno;`.

Comment: I would suggest to declare `slotno` as `primary key` or at least `unique` if you have designed that field to have unique values: in this way, when you're trying to insert a value which has the same `slotno`, then you'll automatically realize where the problem lies inside your workflow.